# Tracker icon is misaligned in activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, activity

Found something different with my [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) today, seems something goes wrong.

[image]

After inspect the element, found the class of it is `choose-tracker-settings`.
As i used to click label location to choose tracker, the added icon is not useful to me. Anyway, the location is not proper.

More details:

- OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.1
- Browser: Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: I noticed that, too. Then forgot to report it. Can also confirm on Firefox as well. It's not useless, btw, it's just in the wrong place. It's the tag badge vs. privilege tracking selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change that caused this bug has been reverted and will be fixed in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: What is the number of **next build**?